# Limit CSS 'resize: both' to bounding box

Tags: html, css

I want to have an resizable element inside an other, larger element that acts as a bounding box. So one can only resize the inner element to the size of the outer element.
Please see my code snippet below:

```css
div {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

p {
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: scroll;
  resize: both;

}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel neque nec magna lacinia commodo in vel ante. Aliquam tincidunt, purus sit amet congue placerat, lacus mauris rhoncus nisl, nec ornare libero purus eget augue. In sed dui placerat nisl cursus aliquet. Integer nisl lorem, maximus et viverra non, aliquet vel arcu. Cras ullamcorper, arcu id molestie scelerisque, est turpis interdum mauris, sit amet pretium mi lectus at metus. Phasellus ornare odio in ipsum faucibus, et tempus est porttitor. Nullam sollicitudin eleifend mi at semper. Vivamus vel neque nec magna lacinia commodo in vel ante. Aliquam tincidunt, purus sit amet congue placerat, lacus mauris rhoncus nisl, nec ornare libero purus eget augue.</p>
</div>
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Edit: Just setting `max-width` in the inner element won't work for me because the inner element could be anywhere inside the outer element.

Comment: is that you are talking about to make your div responsive

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

p {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: scroll;
  resize: both;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel neque nec magna lacinia commodo in vel ante. Aliquam tincidunt, purus sit amet congue placerat, lacus mauris rhoncus nisl, nec ornare libero purus eget augue. In sed dui placerat nisl cursus aliquet. Integer nisl lorem, maximus et viverra non, aliquet vel arcu. Cras ullamcorper, arcu id molestie scelerisque, est turpis interdum mauris, sit amet pretium mi lectus at metus. Phasellus ornare odio in ipsum faucibus, et tempus est porttitor. Nullam sollicitudin eleifend mi at semper. Vivamus vel neque nec magna lacinia commodo in vel ante. Aliquam tincidunt, purus sit amet congue placerat, lacus mauris rhoncus nisl, nec ornare libero purus eget augue.</p>
</div>
```

If you add max-height and max-width to the parent element, then the inner element will be resizable up to the parent's height and width.

Comment: Thank you Nicolae, unfortunately in my real world problem, the inner element can be dragged around so it position changes. So I can not simply set max-width and max-heigth. I guess I could take the position of the inner element relative to the parent and then somehow calculate the max-height and max-width i would need and set that dynamically. But I thought maybe there is a simpler solution.

Comment: No worries, I see, I think if the parent's width/height remain the same when moving the text box around it should still work. Maybe you can add the entire code here so that we can see whole problem if possible.

Comment: I edited my original post to demonstrate the problem with max-width. My entire code contains angular material library for dragging elements around, a bit complicated to make it work as a snippet.

Comment: I understand what you mean now, I think you are looking for a custom solution like this: https://medium.com/the-z/making-a-resizable-div-in-js-is-not-easy-as-you-think-bda19a1bc53d I don't think that what are you trying to achieve is possible using the simple `resize` property from CSS, because in your case  you need to drag the box from all the sides.